# Multiple websites (IIS), one public IP, and domains names with wildcard

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have the following scenario:
One domain (mydomain.com) that I want to point to 3 different IIS websites depending on the subdomain provided.

For instances:

1. **www.mydomain.com** should go to WEBSITE1
2. **[*].mydomain.com** should go to WEBSITE2
3. **[*].admin.mydomain.com** should go to WEBSITE3

This is hosted on a Win 2008 server and I have only one public IP address.

What would be the most feasible solution for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't support wildcard host headers.  You will have to specify the host header for WEBSITE1, and you could set the set up WEBSITE2 as the default site, which would catch any unspecified subdomains, but for WEBSITE3 you will have to add the host headers individually to your site.

Answer (score 0):

A single IP can host multiple web sites with most web servers (assuming you are working with IIS since you identified Windows 2008, but you did not identify specifically). It is a matter of setting up the virtual host configurations on the web server and registering/configuring the domains appropriately to refer to the IP address of the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is step by step reference guide: http://myhosting.com/wiki/Adding_a_Domain_to_IIS_7